# HTTPSConnection figure out what underlying provider is being used

Tags: java, https

I am opening an HTTPSUrlConnection similar to the code below. I want to be sure that a certain provider is being used (the RSA one I loaded). How can I query the HTTPSUrlConnection to determine the provider being used?

```
URL url = new URL("https://myhost:8081/index.html");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
HttpsURLConnection https_conn =     (HttpsURLConnection) conn;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a specific security provider, build an `SSLContext` with it using [`SSLContext.getInstance(protocol, provider)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html#getInstance%28java.lang.String,%20java.security.Provider%29) (with a provider instance or name), then get an `SSLSocketFactory` from this `SSLContext` and then pass it to `HttpsURLConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(...)`.